# Why is the phone number a hyperlink on desktop sites, in my widget?

Tags: widgets

Here is the `widget` function from a widget I created. For the phone number, I don't understand why it is making it into a hyperlink on desktop sites, using the value of the if before (`$gplus`) for the hyperlink. Please can someone explain?

```
class phone_social extends WP_Widget {

    function phone_social() {
        parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = __('Phone and social widget', 'phone_social') );
    }

    function form($instance) {
        if( $instance) {
            //$title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
            $email = esc_attr($instance['email']);
            $facebook = esc_attr($instance['facebook']);
            $twitter = esc_attr($instance['twitter']);
            $gplus = esc_attr($instance['gplus']);
            $telephone = esc_attr($instance['telephone']);
        } 
        else {
            $email = '';
            $facebook = '';
            $twitter = '';
            $gplus = '';
            $telephone = '';
        }
?>

    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('email'); ?>"><?php _e('Email:', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('email'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('email'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('facebook'); ?>"><?php _e('Facebook URL:', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('facebook'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('facebook'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php if(empty($facebook)) { echo "http://";} else { echo $facebook; } ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('twitter'); ?>"><?php _e('Twitter URL:', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('twitter'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('twitter'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php if(empty($twitter)) { echo "http://";} else { echo $twitter; } ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('gplus'); ?>"><?php _e('Google Plus URL:', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('gplus'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('gplus'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php if(empty($gplus)) { echo "http://";} else { echo $gplus; } ?>" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('telephone'); ?>"><?php _e('Telephone ', 'wp_widget_plugin'); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('telephone'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('telephone'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $telephone; ?>" />
    </p>
<?php 
    } // end 'form' function

    function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
        $instance = $old_instance;
        // $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
        $instance['email'] = strip_tags($new_instance['email']);
        $instance['facebook'] = strip_tags($new_instance['facebook']);
        $instance['twitter'] = strip_tags($new_instance['twitter']);
        $instance['gplus'] = strip_tags($new_instance['gplus']);
        $instance['telephone'] = strip_tags($new_instance['telephone']);

        return $instance;
    }

    function widget($args, $instance) { 
        extract( $args );
        $telephone = $instance['telephone'];
        $email = $instance['email'];
        $facebook = $instance['facebook'];
        $twitter = $instance['twitter'];
        $gplus = $instance['gplus'];

        echo $before_widget;
        echo '<div class="widget-text wp_widget_plugin_box" style:>';


        if( $email ) {  
            echo '<a href="mailto:' . antispambot($email) .'" target=""><img src="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/images/email.png" height="24" width="24" alt="email">';  
        } 

        if ( $facebook ) { 
            echo  '<a href="'.$facebook.'" target="_blank"><img src="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/images/fb.png" height="24" width="24" alt="facebook">';  
        }

        if ( $twitter ) { 
            echo  '<a href="'.$twitter.'" target="_blank"><img src="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri ().'/images/twitter.png" height="24" width="24" alt="Twitter">';  
        } 

        if ( $gplus ) { 
            echo  '<a href="'.$gplus.'" target="_blank"><img src="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/images/googleplus.png" height="24" width="24" alt="gplus">';  
        } 

        //If you add an ID to your link inside the wp_is_mobile() conditional, do you see that same ID on the front end?
        if( $telephone ) {
            if ( wp_is_mobile() ) { 
                echo  "<a href='tel:$telephone' id='T_E_S_T'>$telephone </a><br />";
                //tel:$telephone
            }
            else { 
                echo '
                    <div class="widget-textphone">' . $telephone . ' </div> '; 
            }
        } 

        echo '</div>';
        echo $after_widget;
    }
}   
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return register_widget("phone_social");'));
```

Comment: If you add an `ID` to your link inside the `wp_is_mobile()` conditional, do you see that same ID on the front end?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee How should I add the `ID`, please?

Comment: `echo  "<a href='tel:$telephone' id='T_E_S_T'>$telephone </a><br />";` <-- like this.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee No the `ID` isn't displayed on the front end

Comment: Then the code shown above isn't the cause of your phone number having a link, it's happening somewhere else that we do not know about. What happens when you view it on mobile?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee On mobile, the link works like it should do. I'm also seeing `img src="http://mydomain.co.uk/wp-content/themes/testthis/images/email.png" height="24" width="24" alt="email">` in the browser here. So it looks like there is a problem here, but I haven't got a clue what, it looks OK to me.

Comment: I'm not convinced that the code shown reflects the problem. Can you verify that it is 100% this particular code snippet?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I'm not sure. I think it's best if I post the code for the whole widget.

Comment: if you remove or exit of the of the widget (keeping the code above from running) does the phone number still show up? Is the phone number still linked?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee Sorry, but I'm not quite sure what you mean by that.

Comment: at the top of your function, on the first line, before `extract( $args );` add in `exit;` - if the phone number still shows up and is linked, this widget has absolutely nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I added `exit;` before `extract( $args ); ` and the phone number didn't show up. I had `if($telephone)`  before the `if($email)` before, & I didn't have this problem then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I see the problem now. None of your links have a closing anchor tag which is cascading down until it hits the end at which point you close it on phone number:

Your Code:

```
echo  '<a href="'.$facebook.'" target="_blank"><img src="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/images/fb.png" height="24" width="24" alt="facebook">';
```

What it should probably look like:

```
echo  '<a href="'.$facebook.'" target="_blank"><img src="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/images/fb.png" height="24" width="24" alt="facebook"></a>';
```

So after you link your images in your callback function you need to close your anchor tags.

Comment: Thank you so much. That seems to be it. I just need to figure out why it's showing `img src="http://mydomain.co.uk/wp-content/themes/testthis/images/email.png" height="24" width="24" alt="email">` in the browser now. This is my 1st WP website. I can't thank-you enough!!

Comment: No problem, classic mistake that happens to everybody now and then ^_^ good luck!